# In TypeScript, why is an empty array inferred as "any[]" when noImplicitAny is true, and inferred as "never[]" when it is false?

Tags: typescript

```
let a = [];
a.push(0);
```

The code above compiles fine when

1. both `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` are set to true
2. both `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` are set to false

But it issues an error on the second line when

3. `noImplicitAny` is false and `strictNullChecks` is true

The error issued is `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

It seems that in the first two cases `a` is being inferred as a `any[]`, and in the last case it is inferred as a `never[]`, but why does this happen?
If `noImplicitAny` is false, shouldn't it be able to still infer it as `any[]`? Conversely, why is it being inferred as `any[]` in the first case where `noImplicitAny` is true? It seems that the expected behaviors are reversed somehow...

Check the images attached below for the errors and options used.

First two cases:
[image]

Last case:
[image]

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54414

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This issue was raised in [microsoft/TypeScript#36987](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36987).  The authoritative (but not particularly informative) answer there is that this behavior is as intended, and required for backward compatibility.  Generally speaking TypeScript doesn't introduce breaking changes unless these changes improve many more things than they break.

---

When [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) and [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) are both enabled, then empty arrays are not really of type `any[]`; instead they are "auto" or "wildcard" or "evolving" types that change depending on what values are observed to be added to them.  This is implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#11432](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11432):

```
let a = []; // auto-typed
a.push(0); // now a is seen as number[]
a.map(x => x.toFixed()) // okay
a.map(x => x.toUpperCase()) // error, numbers don't have a toUpperCase() method
```

When `--noImplicitAny` is off, this doesn't happen, since doing so would have added new errors to existing code which used to be "fine" (if `a` is of type `any[]`, then `x` in the `map()` method should be of type `any`, and so no error should occur on `x.toUpperCase()` or typos like `x.toFaxed()` or anything).

---

As for the difference between `--strictNullChecks` being on or off, there were several bug fixes having to do with empty array literals interacting badly with other use cases; see [microsoft/TypeScript#19576](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19576) and [microsoft/TypeScript#19745](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19745).  These fixes changed the behavior when `--strictNullChecks` is on, but not when it is off, again to preserve backward compatibility in these other use cases.

---

So that's what's going on, more or less.  You're seeing the consequences of several features and bug fixes interacting in a peculiar way in the face of certain compiler options.

Pragmatically speaking you should always use the full [`--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) where possible.  This gives you a "standard" amount of type safety and is used widely so there's a large amount of documentation and discussion in the community.  If you selectively disable some compiler options and you run into something strange or unexpected, there are fewer resources available to you, because you might be among very few people with such a configuration.  And even if you find a genuine language bug, there will be less pressure for it to be fixed, so it might persist for a long time or forever.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG0C6BuAUFAdABwK4GcALACgAYBKdLAWym2IA84A+CBzMAewDEBLBkABNi5chAD04iJwDWUAJ4AaaBF74I+ECAB20ddtzUARiABOyDJlr0msVuy4BVbNjMBhKJpFjJEM6c5TZRg1DS1dTwgDYzNkKM5IfDBTXm0Ac2QgA)

Comment: jcalz, your typescript answers are so legendary. Thanks!

Comment: See also: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54414 "Report evolving arrays / evolving variables differently in QuickInfo"

Answer (score 9):

This is intended behaviour as it can be observed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13140).

It has mostly to do with backwards compatibility. The main gist is something along these lines

- the type for the array is actually `undefined[]` that gets widened to `any[]`
- but when `strictNullChecks` is true then `undefined` is not an option so it gets updated to `never[]`