# How to resolve Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: angular

In Angular-14, I have this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PaginationService {

    //Pagination Variables

    temppage: number = 0;
    pageField = [];
    exactPageList: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    // On page load
    pageOnLoad() {
        if (this.temppage == 0) {

            this.pageField = [];
            for (var a = 0; a < this.exactPageList; a++) {
                this.pageField[a] = this.temppage + 1;
                this.temppage = this.temppage + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'

and **this.pageField[a]** is highlighted.

How do I get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Change your declaration:

```
pageField = [];
TO
pageField: Number[] =[];
```

It will fix your compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the type of your field `pageField` is  `never[]`.

You can check it when you hoover over `NeverArray.pageField` in this [Stackblitz Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEByCmA3eAnAgilYCe0DeAUNMdAPSnQAuAFvFdgA50CWAJtAHZKoDaAukRIMwAc3gAxZvBDsAvNH4BuAgF8CBUJBiwArgFtUzYBiy5CJaMLGTprAFzQTOADwd9AI1QA+aPKWDiADMAe2CACgBKfACSGmYIADorCSkZHgAGPl9oAEZlCzUVIA)

```js
class NeverArray {
    // the type id never[]
    pageField = [];
}
```

To fix the issue, you should explicitly add the type of the array:

```js
class NumericArray {
    pageField: Array<number> = [];
    foo() {
      this.pageField[0] = 1;
    }
}
```

When you do not explicitly type or initialize an array, the rules are quite tricky: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660888/1041641

Answer (score 0):

If you have `strictNullChecks: true` enabled in your `tsconfig.json`, you need to explicitly type your variables which get passed empty array default values (`[]`) otherwise TypeScript will expect them to always remain as `[]` (the typescript way of saying this is `never[]`)

In your case, `pageField = []` sets the type of `pageField` to be `never[]`. By changing this to `pageField: number[] = []` you are informing TypeScript that `pageField` expects to contain numbers, therefore when a number is passed into that array, there is no error