# Triggering TypeScript error for untyped arrays

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

If I were to type
`const array = []` TypeScript will infer this as `any[]`.

I've been trying to find a workaround for this to fail linting and I can't find a single rule to make this fail linting (either with ESLint or TypeScript).

```
const array = []; //array currently typed as any
array.push('test'); //array currently typed as string[]
array.push(1); //array currently typed as (string | number)[]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be inferred as `never[]`...? What's your tsconfig

Comment: As long as you have `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks` turned on, it probably won't be that big a deal, [the inferred type will change the first time you add something to the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72659865/in-typescript-why-is-an-empty-array-inferred-as-any-when-noimplicitany-is-t)

Comment: @kelsny only if you have `strictNullChecks` but not `noImplicitAny` see the link from my previous comment. The compiler should change the inferred type at the site of first use.

Comment: You are correct, as soon as I add something to it the type changes. I guess i can live with that! I already have noImplicitAny and strictNullChecks turned on.

Comment: Hmm, checking properly, as you add things to the array the type keeps mutating to accept everything.  Ill edit the question to examplify

Comment: I don't think there's a lint rule for that (at least not that I found through googling). There probably should be. IDK my team and I almost never assign an empty array to a variable binding so it isn't something that comes up at work or home for me.

Comment: @michaelpilote "as soon as I add something to it the type changes." --> Just a small correction saying that "type changes" isn't entirely accurate because if that was the case you wouldn't be able to add booleans to the array after adding string and numbers to it for example.

Comment: Technically, the term is _"evolving `any`"_. https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/03/09/evolving-any

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule for this in ESLint core or typescript-eslint. I couldn't find any community-created plugin either.

For now, you could most of the way with the core rule [`no-restricted-syntax`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax). It can be configured to target any arbitrary [ESQuery](https://github.com/estools/esquery) selector(s). This configuration will select any *variable declarator* whose *id* (name) does not have a *type annotation* and whose *init* (initial value) is an an *array element* that has length 0 (no elements):

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error", 
  {
    "message": "Don't use evolving any arrays.",
    "selector": "VariableDeclarator:matches([id.typeAnnotation=undefined]):matches([init.type=ArrayExpression]):matches([init.elements.length=0])"
  }
]
```

[Here's a typescript-eslint playground showing that working](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.tsx&code=MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwSA7gUwCYC4bQE4CWYA5gNoC6MAvDBQNwBQDoksGBEiy6G1t5dIA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQHYHsBaaFAF2gEsBjUxAE0OQE9dSBDAD3TAG1JFo0fNEgAaMOGwQsU7JAC2KZGwDmibpAAi%2BXAHJSYWMkRhEAN3zwzFXCrBtcTe4LZNkAOjGTZUY0hrCGgBqbJRsAEZImohU8KFspMJo8glUABYoABQ8FHTupEwADogAgrgE7KQUOgC8sLh0iABmNvQAugCUyakZyNk2FKT5RYg1JS5MAKIchSTIyNW4nd2k6Vk5uIPuiEiKrB5ItqRpNQAMnZDe2AC%2BV22St9dAA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false). There's probably a more elegant way to write that selector.

---

A cleaner approach would be to have a dedicated lint rule for this. That would bypass having to manage `no-restricted-syntax` options -which can get tricky to do in ESLint config overrides- and would allow for fixers/suggestions from the rule.

I'd definitely recommend [filing an issue on typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/new/choose). I tried searching for an existing issue around evolving any, arrays without type annotations, etc. and couldn't find one. You might want to search for duplicates with your own phrasing as search terms just be sure.

Even if this doesn't become a plugin rule in typescript-eslint, you can always write your own custom ESLint rule and release it as a standalone plugin. [typescript-eslint.io > Custom Rules](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules) has docs on how to work with the tooling for custom rules.